# Reload a gun in Construct 2

Tags: google-play-games, construct-2

I have a game of Zombies in contruct 2, yes i'm very creative, i developed a gun system that shoot when you have bullets in your gun. In case o you don't have a bullets in you gun the system subtract eight bullets to yout bullets and put eight bullets in your gun. The problem is that i cant put time when reload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt724.png)

Comment: There is a System wait you can use: https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/56/how-to-use-the-system-wait-action/en

Answer (score 0):

Use wait statement before player subtracts bullets from totalAmount. After e.g. 3 sec add this amount to currentAmmo variable. It is inside System directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `wait`action before reloading the gun.
For example, you can code like
when the user requests to reload(event)
then `wait x seconds`(action)
then reload (action)
subtract 8 bullets from bullet variable(action)
...
you should understand from there
Learn more about the `wait` action at  scirra.com/tutorials/56/how-to-use-the-system-wait-action/en